# Are banks in Europe allowed to charge you for too low a balance?

Tags: banking, fees, germany, europe

Ever since I've heard stories of people in the U.S. who (almost) emptied their accounts, I've feared of one day doing that too. I always make sure to have at least 100 EUR in each of my accounts. It goes like this: Someone takes everything but 5 USD out of their account. The bank says it's too low and charges them 20 USD. Their balance is now at -15 USD. The bank charges overdraft fees. After some time, their balance is at -16 USD. It's still too low. The bank charges them another 20 USD for having too low of a balance. Their balance is now at -36 USD. The bank charges overdraft fees again. Their balance is now at -38 USD. Etc. Even though they had a positive balance before this fee cascade started.

Are banks in the EU allowed to charge fees for having too low of a balance? I'm not asking about overdraft fees like 20% annually for how much below zero your balance is. I'm asking about either non-relative charges (like 20 EUR for having a balance below 100 EUR or below -1000 EUR) or charges for a balance that's low but not below zero (like 20 EUR if you hit zero or 20% of how much you are below 100 EUR).

If there is no EU-wide regulation, I'd take comfort in there being a Germany-wide law regarding this because I'm German and for the most part use German banks (one in Luxembourg).

Comment: Why don't you ask your banks? You haven't even stated which banks you use nor the type of account you hold with them so no one even has a chance at guessing how your bank operates. Read your ToS.

Comment: The people who get hit with low-balance service charges don't have jobs, or don't shop around for banks without service charges.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Generally speaking, I feel like a big advantage of Europe is that profiteering is mostly illegal. I'd take comfort in knowing that there is a law that prohibits banks from issuing such charges. I already checked for the banks where I have accounts but I'm not sure whether I missed something. Doing that everyt time they change their price charts isn't fun. For one of the banks I'm a customer of, their price chart is 15 pages of mostly double-column small print and I've read the then-current version several times the past few years. -.-

Comment: So you're asking about law rather than specific practices currently in effect? Who's to say that the law won't change? You're asking about Europe as a continent and not a specific country?

Comment: It seems like you're afraid because of hyped up and potentially inaccurate information on how overdraft fees work in the US. You can't be charged overdraft fees because of overdraft fees. And, you can opt out of overdraft "coverage" which means banks will just reject one time transactions that would have caused you to go negative in the first place. Overdraft is essentially a bank giving you a small, very high risk loan, without any chance to evaluate your creditworthiness first - so it makes sense that it's "expensive."

Comment: @dwizum They actually have this chance when I open the account and while I use it.

Comment: @dwizum I was hoping for EU-wide regulation. I added the country tag `Germany` and a short explanation to my question. I can understand perfectly well that banks charge high interest rate for overdraft. However, what I'm asking about is not overdraft but just getting close to or hitting zero.

Comment: A [quick google search about bank fees in Germany](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/first-bank-account-in-germany) reveals that there are definitely banks in Germany that charge monthly fees if your balance is below a certain amount. This seems like an indirect way to answer your question of *are minimum balance fees allowed* - the answer seems to be yes, they are allowed (or, conversely, no - there is no EU-wide regulation that completely prevents them).

Comment: They would not necessarily put it like that, common language is that there is a (perfectly reasonable and difficult to dispute) fee for maintaining an account, which will be “waived” if your balance is over a certain limit. Same thing for credit card use.

Comment: Better specify which country you are looking for in EU. There isn't a EU wide rule for banks charging for accounts. It is mostly decided at the national level.

Comment: @dwizum: It doesn't help that "You can't be charged overdraft fees because of overdraft fees" because the name of the fee isn't particularly important.  You can be charged *other* fees, such as a "sustained negative balance" fee, as a result of overdraft fees.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You asked,

> Are banks in the EU allowed to charge fees for having too low of a balance? I'm not asking about overdraft fees like 20% annually for how much below zero your balance is. I'm asking about either non-relative charges (like 20 EUR for having a balance below 100 EUR or below -1000 EUR) or charges for a balance that's low but not below zero (like 20 EUR if you hit zero or 20% of how much you are below 100 EUR).

Googling reveals evidence that [some banks in Germany do in fact charge low balance fees and others do not.](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/first-bank-account-in-germany) These fees work in the way you're describing - a customer is charged a fixed fee if their balance is below a certain amount.

This evidence seems to indirectly answer your question - because these fees do exist, there must not be any EU-wide or German regulation preventing them.

Comment: Yeah, "9.90€ monthly fee if account balance is below 1200€, free otherwise." is exactly what I meant by "like 20 EUR for having a balance below 100 EUR" in my question.

Comment: `because they do exist`? Do you mean "because they do not exist"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I meant, because the fees exist, there must not be a regulation preventing them. I'll see if I can edit to make that clear.

Comment: Oh I see now. English can certainly be confusing at times. Looks good now :)

Answer (score 1):

To complement [dwizum's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/118937/36669), in my experience, totally free accounts are uncommon in Europe.  Every account I've had charges some small monthly or quarterly maintenance fee regardless of the balance.

Comment: Then you are going to the wrong bank(s). Mine is free.

Comment: @Aganju People keep asking about “Europe” but it does depend a lot on the country. I have never found an offer like that in the Netherlands.

Comment: @Relaxed You can just use a bank of a different EU country. Remittances within the EU are free anyway and it seems to me that you speak English, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @UTF-8 That worked pretty great with Icesave.

Comment: Can confirm. Also recently a lot of the banks that provided free accounts started adding small fees due to (they claim) the negative interest rates of the BCE; some of these waive those fees under certain conditions (e.g. if you get your salary as direct deposit on your account, or if you trade stocks or similar).

Comment: @Aganju you are saying that your account has no minimum required balance nor minimum threshold for direct deposits? You use it however you want and the only way to get charged is via overdraft? I highly doubt it unless you have some weird internet bank with zero customer service.

Comment: Feel free to not believe it. I don't even have a regular deposit from salary, and yes, it is completely free, and the bank has several hundred physical locations in Germany.

Comment: Sounds like OP would be interested in knowing which bank this is since they are so terrified of fees.

Comment: It's Degussa Bank.

Comment: @UTF-8 It doesn't seem so easy to me. It's possible to keep an account alive after moving (I have), it's a little more difficult to open one in a country where you have never been. To be sure, non-resident account do exist, especially for wealthy people, but most retail banks have restrictions and demand quite a bit of paperwork including a proof of residence or even showing up at a branch. Maybe that's easier some place I don't know but that's precisely why it pays to be specific.

Comment: @UTF-8 Case in point: Aganju's bank seems to only serve Germany (website only in German, no way to provide an address anywhere else in the form to create an account), I know several banks offering free accounts in France (and then some: free Gold Mastercard or Visa Premier, no fees on withdrawal abroad), Eric is convinced that it doesn't exist and I have looked extensively but to no avail for something similar in the Netherlands. We were all correct: we are just talking about different countries and shouldn't overestimate how unified the retail banking market really is in the EU.

Comment: I don't have an account with them, but I just googled and the list of countries where you can have your residency and get an account at N26 (seems to be free) reads like the entire developed world. You can live in the U.S. and still have an account with them, so I'm sure their website and apps and whatnot are all available in English.

Comment: As a side note (forgot to mention it): They also don't seem to care about your nationality. At all. You don't need to be a citizen of any of the supported countries. You just need to live there. Most banks don't seem to care. Last week, I helped my gf open a bank account with a German bank (that as I now found out only accepts people who live in Germany, Austria, or Switzerland) and they didn't care that she's from some random 3rd world country on the other side of the world and only is a citizen of that country.

Comment: forget banks. what about credit unions in Europe?